# Sandwich/Squeeze Theorem for Null Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Sandwich Theorem: *Suppose* $(a_{n})\to 0\,$ *and* $\, 0\leq |b_{n}| \leq a_{n}$, *then* $\, (b_{n})\to 0$.

Proof:

Suppose $(a_{n})\to 0\,$ and $\, 0\leq b_{n} \leq a_{n}$

Known result: $x\leq |x|\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R} \Longrightarrow a_{n}\leq |a_{n}|$

By definition of $(a_{n})\to 0$: $\forall \varepsilon>0\,\, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>N, |a_{n}|<\varepsilon$

Also, $\varepsilon>0 \Longleftrightarrow -\varepsilon<0$

Combining the four inequalities gives: $-\varepsilon<0\leq b_{n}\leq a_{n}\leq |a_{n}|<\varepsilon \Longrightarrow |b_{n}|<\varepsilon$ (by interval property of inequalities)

Hence $\forall \varepsilon>0\,\, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>N, |b_{n}|<\varepsilon \longrightarrow (b_{n})\to 0$

So we have: If $(a_{n})\to 0\,$ and $\, 0\leq b_{n} \leq a_{n}$, *then* $\, (b_{n})\to 0\quad$ (1)

And combining with absolute value rule gives the sandwich theorem.

$\\$

In my exercise book it says to prove (1) then combine with the absolute value property. I don't think I have done this correctly as I believe I can just use my method to prove it outright by replacing all $b_{n}$'s with $|b_{n}|$'s. Also I am not sure if my final statement is even a correct conclusion.

Comment: By the definition of limit the statement $(b_n) \to 0$ is equivalent to the statement $(|b_n|) \to 0$. Hence it is enough to prove the result when $b_n=|b_n|$.

Comment: but $b_{n}\leq a_{n}$ is not equivalent to $|b_{n}|\leq a_{n}$